# Weird Arduino LED behaviour

Tags: arduino-uno, led

I noticed something when I was trying something with leds;

```
  pinMode(13,HIGH); // giving +5V to pin 13.
  delay(1000);      // waiting for 1 sec.
  pinMode(13,HIGH); // giving +5V to pin 13 again.
  delay(1000);      // waiting for 1 sec again.

  //loops forever.
```

But I couldn't light the led. What is the reason behind this? Shouldn't it be lit forever?

Comment: Is that the whole program?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams no,the pin is initilized before setup func. and this is in the loop func.

Comment: Maybe you should post the *whole* program then?

Comment: `pinMode` is not the function to use to set a level on a pin, it's used to setup the pin as input, input with pullup, or output. Use `digitalWrite` in your loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already in the comments, you are using `pinMode(...)` where you should be using `digitalWrite(...)`

The code should look like

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT); // sets the pin to an OUTPUT, it can now source or sink current
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH); // sets the pin to +5V
  delay(1000); // waits 1 sec
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
}
```

When you use `pinMode(13, LOW)` you are actually writing `pinMode(13, INPUT)` as `LOW` and `INPUT` are two aliases for the same value (0, by the way).
When in `INPUT` mode the PIN doesn't source or sink any considerable current, so I can't say much more about why the LED is turning on unless you provide a schematics of your circuit (but I have idea you are doing something really wrong).

It might be useful to have a look at [this simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.200277308269968%2050%205%2050%0AR%20224%20112%20176%20112%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20224%20240%20224%20304%200%0A162%20224%20112%20224%20176%201%202.1024259%201%200%200%0Ar%20224%20176%20224%20240%200%20220%0Ar%20368%20176%20368%20240%200%20220%0A162%20368%20112%20368%20176%201%202.1024259%201%200%200%0Ag%20368%20240%20368%20304%200%0AL%20368%20112%20320%20112%200%200%20false%205%200%0AL%20512%20240%20464%20240%200%201%20false%205%200%0A162%20512%20112%20512%20176%201%202.1024259%201%200%200%0Ar%20512%20176%20512%20240%200%20220%0AR%20512%20112%20464%20112%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0A):

- on the left the LED is connected directly to voltage source without control from Arduino
- in the middle, the LED is controlled by Arduino on the high side: click on the letter to toggle the pin state
- on the right the LED is controlled on the low side